# Getting Number of Files in a Directory using Dropbox API

Tags: java, file, dropbox-api

Is this possible? I'm storing some files in a directory. And I want users to see the whole folder. I tried and searched, but couldn't find a way to get the count of files, or the list of files in a directory.

I'm using Java, but I guess it does not matter that much.

Thank you very much already.

Answer (score 3):

You can call [/metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api#metadata) for the desired folder, then count the number of entries in the 'contents' list where 'is_dir' is false. If you're using the official Java SDK, this call corresponds to the [metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-java-sdk-1.5.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#metadata%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

Comment: This will not work if the number of files in the folder exceeds the limit for the folder.

Comment: That's true. In that case, you'd want to use /delta to get and count all of the relevant entries: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta

Comment: This definitely solves OPs question so +1. I wish delta worked for capturing deleted items though like the meta call :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/files/list_folder` API of Dropbox which is https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder

You can refer this at https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder

You have to add headers and Request data for this API and get the Folders and Files in your Dropbox. Make use of it.